# Find $m\angle BEC$. Find $A(ABCD)$=?

Tags: geometry

a) In the figure, $ABCD$ is a rhombus with $|AB|=|BE|$ and $m\angle DCB=56^0$. Find $m\angle BEC$

[image]

My attemp is: $$m\angle DCB=56^0=m\angle DAB=56^0\implies m\angle DFC=m\angle FBC=m\angle DAF=m\angle FAB= 28^0$$
Becouse $\triangle DFC=\triangle BFC=\triangle DFA=\triangle BFA$ whe have:
$$m\angle FDC=62^0=m\angle FBC=m\angle FAB=m\angle FAD$$
From the triangle $BEC$ we have: $m\angle EBC=\pi-m\angle FBC=180^0-62=118^0$
I think $|CE|=|AE|\implies m\angle BEC=28^0$
Now from the triangle $BEC$ we havbe: $m\angle BEC=180^0-(118^0+28)=34^0$ 
I think that is correct, but i didint know. Please help me.

b) $|DE|=|EF|=|FC|$ The shaded area is 1$5cm^2$. Find $A(ABCD)=?$

[image]

Case a) a is good, and case b) please help me
Please helpe me. thanks for your attention and your help

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** GEF and GAB are similar triangles with the ratio $1:3$.

1. What is the ratio $ \frac{GE}{GA} $?
2. What is the area of $GEF$?
3. What is the area of the "much larger rectangle which has G on its side opposite AB"?
4. What is the area of $ABCD$?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105940/discussion-on-answer-by-calvin-lin-find-m-angle-bec-find-aabcd).